# Filtering rows in pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch

If i have tensor which holds information on detected images in following shape:

```
        [[595.00000, 179.62500, 628.00000, 283.00000,   0.89062,   0.00000],
        [142.87500, 167.62500, 201.62500, 324.00000,   0.88086,   0.00000],
        [311.75000, 170.50000, 368.75000, 320.50000,   0.87549,   0.00000],
        [555.50000, 173.75000, 593.50000, 280.50000,   0.85791,   0.00000],
        [398.50000, 179.00000, 425.50000, 265.00000,   0.84180,   0.00000],
        [445.75000, 177.75000, 479.25000, 270.75000,   0.82129,   0.00000]]
```

where each row represents image with following parameters :

```
[   top,    bottom, left,   right, confidence, class    ]
```

What is most effective way of dropping images (rows) that are in size smaller than some user defined input for height which is `top-bottom`?

Naturally I would iterate over rows and than drop each row where `top-bottom < someValue` with some list comprehension but I suspect there could be better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about I drop some benchmarks (if that would be interesting to you)?

**Benchmarks**

PyTorch-ic way:

```
In[2]: import torch
  ...: a = torch.Tensor(
  ...:      [[595.00000, 179.62500, 628.00000, 283.00000,   0.89062,   0.00000],
  ...:         [142.87500, 167.62500, 201.62500, 324.00000,   0.88086,   0.00000],
  ...:         [311.75000, 170.50000, 368.75000, 320.50000,   0.87549,   0.00000],
  ...:         [555.50000, 173.75000, 593.50000, 280.50000,   0.85791,   0.00000],
  ...:         [398.50000, 179.00000, 425.50000, 265.00000,   0.84180,   0.00000],
  ...:         [445.75000, 177.75000, 479.25000, 270.75000,   0.82129,   0.00000]])
In[3]: %timeit a[a[:, 0] - a[:, 1] > 300]
Out[3]: 24.5 µs ± 904 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

In Numpy terms:

```
In[4]: import numpy as np
In[5]: %timeit np_arr[np.where(np_arr[:, 0] - np_arr[:, 1] > 300)]
Out[5]: 4.75 µs ± 713 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In[6]: np_arr[np.where(np_arr[:, 0] - np_arr[:, 1] > 300)]
```

Equity

```
In[7]: torch.equal(torch.from_numpy(np_arr[np.where(np_arr[:, 0] - np_arr[:, 1] > 300)]), a[a[:, 0] - a[:, 1] > 300])
Out[7]: True
```

*Conclusion* is that using numpy for your comparisons would be way faster than PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be:

```
import torch
a = torch.Tensor(
     [[595.00000, 179.62500, 628.00000, 283.00000,   0.89062,   0.00000],
        [142.87500, 167.62500, 201.62500, 324.00000,   0.88086,   0.00000],
        [311.75000, 170.50000, 368.75000, 320.50000,   0.87549,   0.00000],
        [555.50000, 173.75000, 593.50000, 280.50000,   0.85791,   0.00000],
        [398.50000, 179.00000, 425.50000, 265.00000,   0.84180,   0.00000],
        [445.75000, 177.75000, 479.25000, 270.75000,   0.82129,   0.00000]])

y = a[a[:, 0] - a[:, 1] > 300]

print(y)

> tensor([[595.0000, 179.6250, 628.0000, 283.0000,   0.8906,   0.0000],
>         [555.5000, 173.7500, 593.5000, 280.5000,   0.8579,   0.0000]])
```

In case you need to keep only images with height > 300px for example.